# Upcoming birthdays year bug (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my current sql query that gets all the upcoming birthdays for my company in the next 90 days:

```
 SELECT
   user.birthday, user.name, MONTH(user.birthday)
   AS month, DAY(user.birthday) AS day
 FROM user WHERE
   (1 =
   (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL
   90 DAY),birthday) / 365.25)) -
   (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()),birthday)
   / 365.25))) 
 ORDER BY MONTH(birthday),DAY(birthday)
```

The problem, is that if right now is november, and there are some birthdays in january, it will display january birthdays first, then november and then december, although january birthdays already happened THIS year.

Is there a way to reorder this records in the same SQL query, so that it displays current and future months first, and THEN next year's months?

**First partial solution** thanks to Johan

```
ORDER BY ( MONTH(birthday) > MONTH(NOW()             
        OR ((MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(now()) 
            AND DAY(birthday) >= DAY(NOW()) DESC
   , MONTH(birthday), DAY(birthday)
```

Still it needs a little improvement. If a birthday already happened, it should be displayed AFTER december on the results. Example of what should be displayed assuming it is 27th june

- 28 june: john doe
- 27 december: mary wright
- 5 june (next year of course): mad max

Comment: the 5th of june next year will not be selected because it does not fall within the 90 day limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but it seems that your birthday includes the year. If that's so than you'll have a range of birthdays per user (one for every year) and you can just select the ones within the next 90 days.

```
SELECT
  user.birthday
  , user.name
  , MONTH(user.birthday) AS month
  , DAY(user.birthday) AS day  
FROM user 
WHERE  birthday BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW, INTERVAL 90 DAY)  
ORDER BY Birthday DESC
```

If your birthday only has a month and day, your query needs to be:

```
SELECT
  user.birthday
  , user.name
  , MONTH(user.birthday) AS month
  , DAY(user.birthday) AS day  
FROM user 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(birthday),DAY(birthday)),'%YYYY%M%D')
  BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) OR
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)),MONTH(birthday),DAY(birthday)),'%YYYY%M%D')
  BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
ORDER BY ( MONTH(birthday) > MONTH(NOW() 
           OR ((MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(now()) AND DAY(birthday) >= DAY(NOW()) DESC,
         MONTH(birthday), DAY(birthday)
```

Comment: ... but surely the OP's `user.birthdate` is the historical *date of birth* of the users, not each user's upcoming birthday.  (Hence the FLOOR() code for interval calculation in years.)

Comment: exactly, my birthday data is the historical date of birth. i'll try this query and let you know ASAP.

Comment: @pilcrow, I corrected for that in the second query. **if** you store the furture birthdays, you'll get a much faster (and easier) query though.

Comment: @Johan, sorry, I can't run query no. two.  Stray semicolons, missing parens in the ORDER BY and "NOW" rather than "NOW()".  Can you edit?

Comment: @Johan i found a problem with your order query. What if it is june 15... all results of previous days of june (or previous months) will appear BEFORE december birthdays in the results. Any idea on that matter?

Comment: @andufo, fixed the `order by` clause in your question, to match that in my answer.

Comment: @Johan thanks :) but pls check the modified text in the description... that is also a case to consider (im breaking my head trying to come up with a fix for that issue)

Comment: oh now i get it hehe, you modified the original post. it works now and it takes care of that specific issue. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to order using something that includes the year.

```
ORDER by date_format( date, "%d/%m/%Y" )
```

I am no expert but something like this may work too.

```
ORDER BY YEAR(birthday),MONTH(birthday),DAY(birthday)
```

Comment: The second one is right. First it sorts results by year i.e. (2009, 2010, 2011), then by month in years and then by day in months.

Comment: that would not work. Years can be 1989, 1974, 1990... the years the query should worry about is the current and next only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know if each user's birthday, brought in to the current year or the next year, falls between your range:

```
SELECT name, birthday
  FROM (SELECT name, birthday, YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday) AS years_ago
          FROM user) d
 WHERE DATE_ADD(birthday, INTERVAL years_ago YEAR)
           BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
       OR
       DATE_ADD(birthday, INTERVAL (years_ago + 1) YEAR)
           BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

(It occurs to me that you might actually want `INTERVAL 3 MONTH`, rather than `90 DAY`, expecially if you intend to run this query on the first of every month.)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will create a full table scan.

Store an integer containing the day of the year (1st of april is going to be around 90), and compare that with the current day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this code, but I couldn't find a clean/simple query (that also works with leap-years (29th of february problem))

So i've made my own.

Here's the simplest code to get the upcoming birthdays for the next x days, (this query also displays the birthdays of yesterday (or you can change it to a x number of days in the past)

```
SELECT name, date_of_birty 
FROM users 
WHERE DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), RIGHT(date_of_birty, 6)))
        BETWEEN 
            DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        AND
            DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```